# Upgrading Spring 4 to 5.1.3 with JAVA 11 generate runtime errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, java-11

While upgrading Spring to 1.5.3 with JAVA 11, I got run-time exceptions as,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: 
    Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException:
    Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well;
    nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ClassABC$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$488f8dbe.<init>()
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:214)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:473)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:352)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:301)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1749)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException:
    Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well;
    nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ClassABC$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$488f8dbe.<init>()
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:82)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ClassABC$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$488f8dbe.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554)
at deployment.abc.ear//org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:76)
... 46 more
```

I have also updated `spring-aop to 1.5.3`, but still get those errors. Even delete `.m2` directory so there is no dependency version mismatch issue, but no luck.

It seems there is issue in creating proxies. I have added default constructor in some of the classes, but there is too many classes in whole project and changing all of that one by one is headache.

Does anyone has idea, what could be the issue ?

Comment: Can you please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) incl. Maven POM and publish it on GitHub? I think if all we see here are error messages and no code, no Spring configuration and no build configuration, nobody will feel inclined to speculate. Reduce the problem to the smallest reproduceable set of files and show it so we can analyse instead of guess. And please also fix your errors in the question (5.1.3 or 1.5.3?). Thanks.